# How to use volley for curl command line ? (Android - volley)

Tags: java, android, android-volley, bigml

I have already got the model etc. Now I need to use the BigML API to generate the prediction and use it on my android apps. So I read the API documentation and it told me to use curl command (honestly I never know about curl before).

So I tried to use volley (cause iI usually use it) to do the API request. I read almost all questions that similar to this, but I didn't find an answer.

extra info: I've tried to use postman for the curl command, and it worked fine

**THIS IS HOW MY CURL LOOKS LIKE**

```
curl "https://bigml.io/andromeda/prediction?username=USERNAME;api_key=API_KEY"   
-X POST   
-H 'content-type: application/json'  
-d '{"model": "model/5e7ef1081efc9248fa0057f5", "input_data": {"000002": 22.7, "000003": 28.3, "000004": 15.8,"000005": 13.4, "000007": 35}}'
```

Comment: Which Operating System? Windows?

Comment: @muasif80 yea windows sir

Comment: Ok try to put this json in a json file and then use it otherwise escape the double quotes with \ and don't enclose this line with single quote. Better is to use a file and use that as input rather than putting in on inline